# Selenium Wait Until using Element rather the By

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

Afternoon,

I could use a little advise. I have page object setup for example

```
         IWebElement SiteInUse => DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("site-txt"));
```

I have a method set up that will
1. Wait till the element is visible.
2. Check the Elements text is correct.

I am trying to above doing something like

```
WaitHelpers.WaitTillVisiible(By.ClassName("site-txt"));
```

as if the id changes I will need to edit it in two places. I am trying to create a extension method for IWebElement.

I have tried

```
ublic static bool WaitUntilElementIsVisible(this IWebElement element)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverContext.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
       return wait.Until(ElementIsVisible(element));


    }
    public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> ElementIsVisible(IWebElement element)
    {
        return (driver) =>
        {

            try
            {
                return element.Displayed;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // If element is null, stale or if it cannot be located
                return false;
            }
```

This works but only if the element is visible but will not continue to look for the 30 seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exception are you getting? What is the stack trace?

Comment: Its an Element to visible exception. When waiting the process it doesn't wait for 30 seconds and just fails

Comment: Did you mean `ElementNotVisible` exception?

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will attempt to answer given the original problem, which was needing to test for visibility, but this required you to update a locator in two places.

The answer is insanely simple: define a instance field for the locator:

```cs
public class SomePageModel
{
    By siteInUseLocator = By.ClassName("site-txt");

    IWebElement SiteInUse => DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(siteInUseLocator);

    ...
}
```

Then later on you can reuse this field to test for visibility:

```
WaitHelpers.WaitTillVisiible(siteInUseLocator);
```

Comment: that is insanely simple! Wow that embarrassing! I had a bad day yesterday spent two hours yesterday debug an incorrectly named property.